# Updating a record in GORM by returning the values of a slice?

Tags: go, slice, go-gorm

While creating a CLI app, I ran into a problem saving data in bulk with GORM.

Specifically, the use of a slice containing values to be saved as a many2many relationship.

The command `eddie track mood -q 9 --tags=one,two,three,four -i` creates statically fine like so:

```
two := &schema.Record{
    Type: "mood",
    Quality: 9,
    Tags: []schema.Tag{
        {Name: "one"},{Name: "two"},{Name: "three"},{Name: "four"},
    },
    Important: false,
}
```

But... with a for/range loop, I am only picking up the final (which I guess is obvious why), so the `db.Create(&two)` returns one tag, not multiple.

```
var t []schema.Tag
for _, v := range tags {
    t = []schema.Tag{{Name: v}}
}
r := &schema.Record{
    Type: "mood",
    Quality: q,
    Tags: t,
    Important: i,
}
database.Create(&r)
fmt.Printf("You rated your mood a %d.\n", q)
fmt.Println("Record ID:", r.ID)
fmt.Println("Tags:", r.Tags)
return err

You rated your mood a 9.
Record ID: 11
Tags: [{four}]
```

Things I have considered:

- I do not want to save "one,two,three,four" as a single input, parsing later
- Bulk updates do not persist ID, relationships (keys), so this should (from my understanding) be a single `db.Create()` or use an omit, then update immediately after
- I am new to Go (PHP developer for past 8 yrs) so I need some help!
- I may have set my structs up incorrectly?

**How can I bulk update a record in GORM when returning the values of a slice?**

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a slice of strings representing tags.  You want to convert (or map) the tag strings to a slice of schema.Tag, and set the Name property of the schema.Tag to the corresponding tag string.  Then your schema.Record is ready to create.  It looks like you found a way to accomplish that in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I believe I have found a fix.

```
func parse(t []string) []schema.Tag {

    var tags []schema.Tag

    for i := 0; i < len(t); i++ {
        tag := []schema.Tag{{Name: t[i]}}
        tags = append(tags, tag...)
    }

    return tags
}
```

This has given me the following output:

```
You rated your mood a 9.
Record ID: 28
Tags: [{Stackoverflow} {Code} {SNL} {IASIP} {Excited}]
```

Would love some additional help or discussion around this if anyone has anything to add.